# Node Load performance

Tags: 8, entities, nodes

I have a small question.

If I use `Node::Load` on the route of the same node for example:
I go to `site.com/node/125` and in preprocess I use `Node::Load(125)`, would Drupal load that node all over again? Or is there some part in the code where it loads it without any performance impact?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Entities are statically cached in memory, so there is no performance impact if you load the same entity multiple times within the same request.

Answer (score 3):

Actually there is no reason to load the node on all node pages.

When using `MYTHEME_preprocess_node` you have `$variable['node']` that is the loaded node.

Comment: yes i know but sometimes I am using other hooks on a page where a node is already loaded (a block for example) and I have no access for the node, so I take the current url and get the node ID from it, and then I use that ID to load the node.

Comment: Ok, it was just because you wrote that you loaded it in your preprocessing, then I just wanted to tell that was unnecessary, ;)